# Old-style 'you have new comments' topbar reappeared

Tags: support, top-bar

I was surprised to see the old *"You have 2 new comments. See your responses."* top bar when I came to the site earlier today:

[image: Old-style top-bar notification]

I don't recall having seen this for some time, with the global inbox having taken over. Also note that it was wrong, I had *one* new comment, not two. I'd already seen the earlier one. (And I think the global inbox got that right. I *think* it said "1 new comment" when I clicked it, but I can't be absolutely certain.)

Is the "new comments" top bar still active? Or did something hiccup?

---

**Update**: So below, Jeff said that it's still around and has been for a long time. And yet, I almost never see it. Today I came to SO after being away for several hours, using my usual bookmark as I did above. And you can see, the global inbox had SO comments highlighted (it had a red (3) before I clicked it to show them), but no top-bar appeared at all:

[image]

The rules for when it does and doesn't appear would seem to be non-obvious. It certainly *seems* anomalous.

Comment: funnily enough, I'm _not_ seeing that bar for badges today. Just got one and didn't get the notification as I used to... (never seen that for comments though).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder could you [hop](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/402/t-j-crowder-and-genesis) to chat room for one second please?

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this recently as well. It doesn't appear for *all* of my comments, just *some* of them. I haven't figured out a pattern. Perhaps it's when you haven't visited the site for some time?

Comment: @Cody: Not in this case. I'd been to the site like half an hour earlier.

Comment: I noticed this twice, lately. I also noticed that the global inbox doesn't notifies me of all the new comments, or answers, too.

Comment: I've seen it on sites I haven't visited lately, where the GI did give me notification, and I saw it there, but never visited the site. I think that's what happens here, you see it in the GI, don't visit, it doesn't clear it on the far site, and then when you do visit, it has the old reminder code still.

Answer (score 1):

It is still active and has been for a long, long time.

This only appears when you've been away from the site for some time, and drives to the responses tab of your user page which is a slightly different thing.

Comment: The rules around when it appears would seem to be...non-obvious, as in the case where it showed up above, I'd been away for about 30 minutes or so, whereas I frequently come to SO having been away for hours at a time, and have notifications (for SO) in the global inbox, and no top-bar showing. Can you clarify when it does, and doesn't, appear?

Comment: And until when will it be?

Comment: No comment? It doesn't appear to behave as you described.